# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection causing bad memory leak

Tags: dependency-injection, memory-leaks, .net-6.0

I am new to .NET core and DI. The following is a class I wrote in a .Net 6.0 server app to use **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**. It is causing serious memory leaks at the magnitude of +0.5 to 1 MB/minute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FrontEdge.SkyBridge.TcpConnectionsServer
{
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        private static ServiceProvider m_serviceProvider = null;


        public static void Init(Func<IDatabase> createDatabaseMethod)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IDatabase, MySqlServer>();
            m_serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public static IDatabase GetDatabase()
        {
            return m_serviceProvider.GetService<IDatabase>();
        }
    }
}
```

MySqlServer is a scaffold DB context class generate by Entity Framework from my SQL Server database. This is how I call the **GetDatabase()** method:

```
                using (var db = DependencyInjection.GetDatabase())
                {
                    foreach (var appSettingPair in db.GetAppSettingsInDatabase())
                        dictSettings.Add(appSettingPair.Key, appSettingPair.Value);
                }
```

This GetDatabase method is called constantly and the MySqlServer is swiftly disposed of every time it is called.

I did a diff on two heap dumps using **dotnet-gcdump** and Visual Studio, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection seems to be causing all the memory leaks.

[image]

I removed the use of DI, the memory leak stopped.

I want to find out why/how Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection caused memory leak.

Comment: You are resolving `MySqlServer` from the root `IServiceProvider` instead of an `IServiceScope`. If `MySqlServer` implements `IDisposable` (or `IAsyncDisposable`), it will stay referenced until the root `IServiceProvider` is disposed of. This is [known behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#disposable-transient-services-captured-by-container) of MS.DI.